# Intellij 2019.3 sluggish on very large resolution. How to tune parameters for performance?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

On MacOS, using Intellij 2019.3 I am experiencing annoying lag when scrolling.

I am using a MacOS **smoothscroller** global application, which basically adjust the scroll speed with software to get it smooth, but this lagging seems to occur also for normal mouse scrolling, when this is disabled. Not in all files, but seems to be in those where a rescroll has to load colors or whatnot in next view.

The scrolling works **fine/great** in any other application, but Intellij's implementation of this seems **below** **standard**.

```
The settings I have now (turned up): 

    -Xms1024m
    -Xmx8092m
    -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048m
    -XX:+UseCompressedOops
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
    -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=512
    -ea
    -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
    -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
    -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
    -Xverify:none
```

Can these be modified further? -ea isn't that a server option? Some of you will state that such huge params will cause issues, but I'd like to point out behaviour was the same 30 minutes ago with much lower values everything.

Also **registry** in Intellij lists a bunch of option which are **impossible** to **comprehend** and get right but they are able to adjust the scrolling and enable some "**true.scroll**" stuff which is impossible to adjust properly.

Of course, there are **plugins** to intellij for **scrolling** which are all now broken because Intellij breaks plugins by policy when it rolls out an update *( Editor has been below satisfaction since 2010 )*.

Registry currently:

[image]

Smooth related options (could some be left behind form uninstalled smooth related plugins?):

[image]
[image]

Note that now when I went to screenshot the registry, scrolling there is smooth as I want it to be, however when I scroll actual code, is where Intellij seems to go bonkers. It even does that for a large json file that I scroll.

Could it be due to **highlighting**/**color** **plugins** that is supposed to do stuff as I scroll up? I have minimal stuff installed.

The sluggishness is killing smooth scrolling and productivity. I can not scroll up without a lag and loose focus on where I am supposed to be on screen.

Is there some param there that I should be changing?

Other preferences(defaults):

[image]

Comment: I can add to this the lagging seems to increase considerably when the computer is under some kind of load. It seems like maybe the scrolling part is shared between other threads and intellij threadpool is limited. Yea, NIO. I am on a i9 9900K if you are wondering. 128G. And a Radeon RX Vega 64 graphics card. And an NME disk. Not the computer that is the problem. I can not function like this. Does Intellij provide support for hardware acceleration at all?

Comment: The answer to the sluggish behaviour was the use of show whitespaces. I had all three of them checked. I guess intellij can't rerender the dots on scrolling in a large file. 3 hours later.

Comment: I can verify that I had the same issue on OS X with IntellijIDEA 2019.3 (CE) and turning off all three "show whitespaces" settings made scrolling responsive again.

Comment: Does [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228027#focus=streamItem-27-3834258.0-0) help?

Comment: Andrey No, it does not. I tried everything, and the only thing that made an impact was turning off the whitespace stuff. @cstroe did you do that before or after my suggestion? maybe you found this here by googling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sluggish behavior was due to the use of show whitespaces.

I had all three of them checked.

I guess Intellij can't re render the dots on scrolling in a large file.

3 hours later after testing 100 things.

[image]

Also modifying/disabling antialiasing seems to help.

Found relevant link although in 2019 nothing of it seemed to contribute to any improvements:

https://gist.github.com/finalfantasia/cb8041996f540a158f18

Comment: I should say it is better. In some files, there is still a little barely noticable lag. Maybe time for Intellij team to reimplement some of this?

Comment: Also disabling antialiasing seems to help further.